# How to add shadow to just UIButton border and not to text

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

Right now I am using this piece of code:

```
    donorButton.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.red
    donorButton.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 2)
    donorButton.layer.shadowRadius = 2
    donorButton.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
```

And following is the output, whereas I want to get rid of the shadow on the text
[image: UIButton with shadow on border and text]

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, there are 2 solutions for your question.

1. If you don't care about button background color, just need to change background color of button to non-transparent color.

   ```
   donorButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
   ```
2. If you need a transparent background.

   - Give your button an empty text.
   - Put an `UILabel` below your button and give it same constraints with your button.
   - Set `label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center`

**Result**

[image]